# System.lineSeparator() not working as expected on Windows

Tags: java, cross-platform, newline, java-7

I have a method that takes an string as input, and takes away from it all the spaces and newline characters on it. To achieve this I'm using the following methods from the java libraries:

```
public String clean(String s) {
    return s.replaceAll(System.lineSeparator(),"").replaceAll(" ","");
}
```

This is working fine under Linux, but when it comes to windows, it isn't able to remove the line separator characters, as the string contains them.

Is there something I'm missing? I know in Unix based systems the newline character is /n and I have no clue what might it be in Windows, but as the java documentation says, the System.lineSeparator() method should provide a platform-independent line separator character.

Comment: In windows its sometimes \r\n maybe that's the issue?

Comment: @WilliamMorrison Or even `\r\n` ;)

Comment: Thanks, noticed you edited your post too. Sweet. Nailed it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest you try this as you are removing spaces

```
public static String clean(String s) {
    return s.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
}
```

I suspect the problem you have is that you are reading files written on windows on a linux box.  You code won't remove the extra `\r` that you have on Windows.

Comment: A linux box? Do you mean a virtual machine? I have tested this on two different computers, both running windows, not virtual machine. 
But anyway I'm curious, woudln't the JVM in the Windows virtual machine be the windows' version, and thus have the right newline character?

Comment: It will be the same on all Windows systems by definition.  It is more likely the files are not exactly the same.

Comment: I can tell the file I'm using is the same, as It's packed in the jar file.

Anyway your "\\s+" worked just fine, but I thought it was just \\s, what's the difference between that and the \\s+, the \\s didn't work for me, so I'm curious.

Comment: Fyi, in my experience, When someone refers to a linux box, windows box etc. They typically mean a physical computer with that operating system installed. As pete said though, there should be no difference code wise.

Comment: @Setzer22 Using `\\s+` is a micro-optimisation.  It means replace multiple spaces at once if you can, instead of replacing one at a time.  Otherwise it also does exactly the same thing as `\\s`.  I would check which version of Java you have or re-install Java because if this also makes a difference I would suspect yours is broken.

Comment: Nevermind, it worked now with \\s as well. It may have been any other error in the code which caused the \\s to fail before, as I can't reproduce that issue with the code I've got right now...

Anyway thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing all `\n` as well as `\r\n`. Yes, lineSeparator should have taken care of this, but perhaps it did not.

Comment: I used \\s+ which refers to all space/newline-like characters like Peter pointed out in the other answer and it worked, but I'm still curious on why didn't lineSeparator return the full \r\n string...

Comment: Ah ok, that makes me feel better. I didn't even know about \\s! Be sure to accept his answer.